# Do we want questions about what software runs a web site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Exhibit A:

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/83071/

I was going to vote to close it, but none of our off-topic reasons seem to fit. It's not idle curiosity, nor is it really about creating or administering a web site of one's own.

On the face of it, it seems like a reasonable, and answerable, question. It might even be useful to a general user in that if you know a particular e-commerce engine is compromised, say, you'd want to avoid sites that use it.

On the other hand, it's not really a question about using a Web app. If the question were, say, "How do I pay with MasterCard on dresslilly.com?" and the answer is "You can't, because they use the Hurgleburgle ecommerce engine and they don't support it", that would fit. But that's not what it is.

Anyway, I'm of the opinion that questions like this don't belong here.

- Do you agree?
- What is an appropriate close reason for questions like this?
- Is there a Stack Exchange site that would accept such questions?
- Do we need to clarify any of our on-topic/off-topic guidance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with you they don't belong on Web Apps - our target is Web Apps end users and I don't think most end users would be concerned about what runs on their webapp.

So to answer:

- yes, agreed
- We can use custom comment one on the lines of "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this pertains to webapp internals"
- I don't think we have such a site, though there are couple of questions on Stack Overflow, and maybe Web Masters on "How to determine what a site runs on" - ex: [How do you determine what technology a website is built on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396739/how-do-you-determine-what-technology-a-website-is-built-on)
- No, I don't think it's needed as of now